# Unlink doesn't work for gzipped files that I downloaded using guzzle

Tags: php, file, unlink

I download lots of gzipped files with foreach loop, in every loop unzip the file. Up to this point everything is okay, but end of the loop I want to unlink the gzipped file. Codes are below.

```
...
... // Previous processes
...

$destinationPath = './files/lld/' . $data['hour'] . '.gz';
fopen($destinationPath, 'w+');

...
... // Download processes
...

// Unzip
$gzfile = gzopen($destinationPath, "rb");
$tsvFile = fopen($destinationTsvPath, "w");

while ( ! gzeof($gzfile)) 
{
    $string = gzread($gzfile, 4096);
    fwrite($tsvFile, $string, strlen($string));
}

gzclose($gzfile);
fclose($tsvFile);

// Delete
unlink($destinationPath);
```

Except the unlink process everything is working, and there is no any error log. I have read similar questions in this site, one of the answers is to use unlink() after gzlose() function. I have tried but there is no result.

Comment: can you enable error reporting and check what PHP errors/warnings you get?

Comment: I don't see yourself `fclose($destinationPath)`-ing.

Comment: @ccKep You are right I addeed fclose($destinationPath), but problem is not resolved.

Comment: @edvinas.me error code is that -> Permission is denied.

Comment: How is the file that `$destinationPath` points to created? You might want to show a bit more of your download code in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have enough permissions to remove the file. I suggest you perform a chmod before `unlink()` like this (this will try to change permission):

```
fclose($destinationPath);
chmod($destinationPath, 777);
unlink($destinationPath);
```

If this does not work, then set directory, where you are storing those files, permission to `775`. You can do this via SSH or FTP.